# AGIC deployed with helm (shared:true) with customized prohibited targets deletes the manually added https listener, rules, pool etc

Tags: azure, azure-aks, azure-application-gateway, ingress-controller

We have a cluster with AGIC that was installed by helm. We made sure to set `shared: true` to helm configs and to delete the default `prohibited-target-all` and introduce the custom prohibited target to blacklist by specific host in order to avoid the deletion of the listener, rules, backend pool, settings that are configured manually on the Application Gateway. Nevertheless, with every deployment AGIC deletes all these manual configurations. I will be very grateful for your help!

Output of `kubectl logs :
According to the logs, the configurations are at first correctly filtered and blacklisted:

```
I0906 15:58:11.491541       1 routing_rules.go:96] [brownfield] Existing Blacklisted Rules AGIC will retain: portal-ui-rule
I0906 15:58:11.491546       1 routing_rules.go:97] [brownfield] Existing Rules AGIC will remove: n/a
I0906 15:58:11.501695       1 mutate_app_gateway.go:174] Generated config:
```

And the following generated config contains the necessary manually added rules and listeners. But then I can see the error:

```
I0906 15:58:34.859958       1 mutate_app_gateway.go:183] END AppGateway deployment
E0906 15:58:34.860028       1 controller.go:141] Code="Canceled" Message="Operation was canceled." Details=[{"code":"CanceledAndSupersededDueToAnotherOperation","message":"Operation PutApplicationGatewayOperation (76a360f0-e06e-4020-b117-94961cae6a8d) was canceled and superseded by operation PutApplicationGatewayOperation (5791956c-6571-4b7e-b9d2-34271255a173)."}]
E0906 15:58:34.860041       1 worker.go:62] Error processing event.Code="Canceled" Message="Operation was canceled." Details=[{"code":"CanceledAndSupersededDueToAnotherOperation","message":"Operation PutApplicationGatewayOperation (76a360f0-e06e-4020-b117-94961cae6a8d) was canceled and superseded by operation PutApplicationGatewayOperation (5791956c-6571-4b7e-b9d2-34271255a173)."}]
I0906 15:58:34.860064       1 event.go:282] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Pod", Namespace:"default", Name:"ingress-azure-5569bddc4c-xkzk2", UID:"85370f16-57b4-4e01-9410-6bcf326fbe7d", APIVersion:"v1", ResourceVersion:"75634", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Warning' reason: 'FailedApplyingAppGwConfig' Code="Canceled" Message="Operation was canceled." Details=[{"code":"CanceledAndSupersededDueToAnotherOperation","message":"Operation PutApplicationGatewayOperation (76a360f0-e06e-4020-b117-94961cae6a8d) was canceled and superseded by operation PutApplicationGatewayOperation (5791956c-6571-4b7e-b9d2-34271255a173)."}]
```

And then the new operation of deployment starts:

```
mutate_app_gateway.go:70] Existing App Gateway config: *_/..configs that are already without my manual listeners and rules ./_*

I0906 15:58:40.953953       1 routing_rules.go:96] [brownfield] Existing Blacklisted Rules AGIC will retain: n/a
I0906 15:58:40.953958       1 routing_rules.go:97] [brownfield] Existing Rules AGIC will remove: n/a
I0906 15:58:40.968738       1 mutate_app_gateway.go:174] Generated config: *_/..configs that are already without my manual listeners and rules ./_*
```

Comment: "CanceledAndSupersededDueToAnotherOperation"

for this error: if customer performed multiple PUT operations in quick succession on the same app resource, then the previous one gets cancelled and superseded by the new one